# How to create this graphic with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to create a graphice like the following:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    \newcommand{\psign}{+}
    \newcommand{\ppsign}{++}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{my node} = [draw,rectangle,minimum width=2.2cm,minimum height=0.8cm, node distance=2cm]
    %\draw[black!20] (-0.5cm,-0.5cm) grid (14cm,7cm);
    \node [my node] (A) {GDI DDI};
    \node [my node] (B) [above of=A] {GDI};

    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \node                       (C)     {Graphics Driver};
    \node [my node] (D) [above of=C]    {GDI\psign Flat API};
    \node [my node] (E) [above of=D]    {GDI\psign\ C\ppsign API};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node [my node] (F) {DX DDI};
    \node [my node] (G) [above of=F] {DXGI};
    \node [my node] (H) [above of=G] {Direct3D};
    \node [my node] (I) [above of=H,minimum width=4cm,right=0pt] {Direct2D};
    \node [my node] (J) [right of=I,right=0pt,node distance=3cm] {DirectWrite};
    \node [my node] (K) [right of=F, node distance=4cm] {Software Rasterizer};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[->,>=triangle 45,semithick]
    \path (B) edge (A);
    \path (E) edge (D);
    \path (H) edge (G);
    \path (G) edge (F);
    \path (J) edge (I);
    \end{scope}

    \draw [dashed] (-1.25,1cm) -- (14,1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to add an image of what your MWE ends up as and write what exactly you need. As was as I know the gray area can be done with the fit feature, see for example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/BER-measurement/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,fit,backgrounds}

\definecolor{fcolor}{HTML}{F1F1F1}

\newcommand{\psign}{+}
\newcommand{\ppsign}{++}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{my node} = [draw,rectangle,minimum width=2.2cm,minimum height=0.8cm, node distance=2cm]
%\draw[black!20] (-0.5cm,-0.5cm) grid (14cm,7cm);
\node [my node] (A) {GDI DDI};
\node [my node] (B) [above of=A] {GDI};

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\node                       (C)     {Graphics Driver};
\node [my node] (D) [above of=C]    {GDI\psign Flat API};
\node [my node] (E) [above of=D]    {GDI\psign\ C\ppsign API};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\node [my node] (F) {DX DDI};
\node [my node] (G) [fill=white,above of=F] {DXGI};
\node [my node] (H) [fill=white,above of=G] {Direct3D};
\node [my node] (I) [fill=white,above of=H,minimum width=4.5cm,right=0pt] {Direct2D};
\node [my node] (J) [fill=white,right of=I,right=0pt,node distance=3.5cm] {DirectWrite};
\node [my node] (K) [fill=white,right of=G, node distance=4cm] {Software Rasterizer};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[->,>=triangle 45,semithick]
\path (B) edge (A);
\path (E) edge (D);
\path (H) edge (G);
\path (G) edge (F);
\path (J) edge (I);
\path (I.south-|K) edge (K);
\path (I.south-|{$(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$}) edge ($(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[rectangle,fill=fcolor,fit=(G.south west) (J.north east)] {};
\end{scope}

\draw [dashed] (-1.25,1cm) -- (14,1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

First I fixed the `Software Rasterizer` node placement `right of=G`:

```
\node [my node] (K) [right of=G, node distance=4cm] {Software Rasterizer};
```

Then, for the remaining two arrow connections, I added to your `edge`s these two lines:

```
\path (I.south-|K) edge (K);
\path (I.south-|{$(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$}) edge ($(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$);
```

Here, `(I.south-|K)` is the point on `Direct2D` node directly above the center of `Software Rasterizer` node. The same idea for `(I.south-|{$(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$})`, but a little complicated. Now it is the point on `Direct2D` node directly above the mid-point between north and north-east of `Direct3D` node.

The highlighted five blocks can be obtained by the `fit` library, but this time within a scope (`on background layer`) to avoid drawing the nodes twice. We select any two outermost nodes like `G` and `J` and specify their outermost corners, `(G.south west)` and `(J.north east)`, respectively.

Comment: Nice one. Learned a bit more. Did wonder about that fit background.

Comment: Well, it's a secret, but I'll uncover it to you. All browsers seem to allow one to see the underlying `html` code of the page. You can simply show the code and whenever you point to an area the font colors and background will be displayed. I just copied it from the OP's picture.

Comment: That is not what  I meant. It was the "on background layer" trick. Didn't know that one.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of does what you are looking for. Note that `fit` draws on top, you if you need a full color underneath, you may need to draw those nodes twice (onces to get the nodes for the `fit` calculation, and once to draw them again onto of the fit area, you can just store the drawing code in a macro and run that macro twice).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
    \newcommand{\psign}{+}
    \newcommand{\ppsign}{++}

    \begin{document}

    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{my node} = [draw,rectangle,minimum width=2.2cm,minimum height=0.8cm, node distance=2cm]
    %\draw[black!20] (-0.5cm,-0.5cm) grid (14cm,7cm);
    \node [my node] (A) {GDI DDI};
    \node [my node] (B) [above of=A] {GDI};

    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \node                       (C)     {Graphics Driver};
    \node [my node] (D) [above of=C]    {GDI\psign Flat API};
    \node [my node] (E) [above of=D]    {GDI\psign\ C\ppsign API};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
    \node [my node] (F) {DX DDI};
    \node [my node] (G) [above of=F] {DXGI};
    \node [my node] (H) [above of=G] {Direct3D};
    \node [my node] (I) [above of=H,minimum width=4cm,right=0pt] {Direct2D};
    \node [my node] (J) [right of=I,right=0pt,node distance=3cm] {DirectWrite};
    \node [my node] (K) [right of=G, node distance=4cm] {Software Rasterizer};
    \end{scope}


  \begin{scope}[ transform canvas={xshift=1cm},
    ->,>=triangle 45,semithick]
    \draw (I)  --  (I |- K.north);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[ transform canvas={xshift=-4em},
    ->,>=triangle 45,semithick]
    \draw (I)  --  (I |- H.north);
  \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[->,>=triangle 45,semithick]
    \path (B) edge (A);
    \path (E) edge (D);
    \path (H) edge (G);
    \path (G) edge (F);
    \path (J) edge (I);
    \end{scope}

    \draw [dashed] (-1.25,1cm) -- (14,1cm);


    \node [fill=gray,opacity=0.2,dotted,fit = (H) (I) (J) (K) ] {};



    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

I assume you can figure out how to add the legend above the gray area.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly modified ind simplified  @daleif and @ AboAmmar solutions (they seems to me almost the same :-)):

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1mm,
               tikz,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,fit,backgrounds}
    \newcommand{\psign}{+}
    \newcommand{\ppsign}{++}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2cm,
every node/.style = {draw, rectangle,
                    fill=white, % if you liked, otherwise should be omitted
                     minimum width=2.2cm, minimum height=0.8cm}
                    ]
\node  (A) {GDI DDI};
\node  (B) [above of=A] {GDI};

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\node  (C) [draw=none]     {Graphics Driver};
\node  (D) [above of=C]    {GDI\psign Flat API};
\node  (E) [above of=D]    {GDI\psign\ C\ppsign API};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\node  (F) {DX DDI};
\node  (G) [above of=F] {DXGI};
\node  (H) [above of=G] {Direct3D};
\node  (I) [above of=H,minimum width=4.5cm,right=0pt] {Direct2D};
\node  (J) [right of=I,right=0pt,node distance=3.5cm] {DirectWrite};
\node  (K) [right of=G, node distance=4cm] {Software Rasterizer};
\end{scope}

\coordinate (L) at ([xshift=7mm] H.north);
\path[-triangle 45,semithick]
    (B) edge (A)    (E) edge (D)    (H) edge (G)
    (G) edge (F)    (J) edge (I)    (I.south-|K) edge (K)
    (I.south -| L) edge (L)
    (I.south-|{$(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$}) -- ($(H.north)!.5!(H.north east)$);

\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (M) [rectangle,fill=gray!30,fit=(G.south west) (J.north east)] {};

\coordinate (N) at ($(A.west)!0.5!(B.west)$);
\draw [dashed]  (N) -- (N -| M.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

This code gives:

[image]

Comment: You are missing an arrow.

Comment: @daleif, yes, I see this now. Apparently in editing of copied code I erroneously erase it. I will fix this.